# how to view two pages of pdf on landscape mode in ios?

Tags: ios, pdf

I have taken Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html and it works perfectly,I have added swiping gestures for turning the pages and it works fine.But I don't have any idea to display two pages side by side on landscape mode,please help.

Comment: did u found out something ?

Comment: yes, i just splitted the view into two and displayed the pdf page on each half of the view